# Pre-check Django admin checkboxes

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Consider a Django Admin changelist view looking somewhat like this:

[image]

I would like to pre-check some of the checkboxes in the list. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/) didn't help me further.

Any ideas on how to achieve this in a nice way? Where by nice I mean, *as standard as possible*.

Answer (score 2):

You could tick the checkboxes using JavaScript. For example, to tick the checkbox for the item with primary key 1, using jQuery, you would do:

```
$(".action-select[value='1']").prop('checked', true);
```

Or you could use Django's bundled jQuery if you want:

```
django.jQuery(".action-select[value='1']").prop('checked', true);
```